# org.enhydra.shark.api.* packages is missing

Tags: java, opentaps

I want to develop http://www.opentaps.org crm .I've downloaded sources and imported to IDE and ... ,
the problem is that the library which contains org.enhydra.shark.api doesn't exist . I've downloaded  jped-2.0.jar library but it contains just org.enhydra.shark.utilities and xpdl but not api packages .
does any body know where I can find these packages ? in which library and which version ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Opentaps are you running ? did you clone from the master git repository ?

are you trying to compile the code in the ide?  I suggest you run ./ant inside the project and don't use the ide to compile

Comment: thank you for your answer , I download source zip file of opentaps 1.5 from sourceforge , I want to compile it in IDE because I want to develop on it , where I can get newest version of opentaps svn or git  url ?

Comment: you can get it from https://github.com/opentaps/opentaps-1.   You can open the code in the ide and edit there but you should not compile it from it but using the terminal with ant or the appropriate command in your case.

Comment: is it the latest version ?